# Catalog Price Rules mess when using multiple conditions

Tags: price, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, special-price

I'm trying to set up some discounts on manufacturers products, but I need to be able to apply different discounts on some categories.

Example:
If manufacturer: ford, discount is 25%
If manufacturer: ford and Category: services, discount is 45%

Now, if I create such rules, then I get a discount of 59% for products on category Services and some of the products with manufacturer: ford don't have any discount at all.

I've also tried:
Manufacturer: ford, category not services, discount 25
Manufacturer: ford and Category: services, discount is 45

This works a bit different, I still get a few products without any discounts but the products that get the 45% discount are rounded up and the discount might get up to 47% automatically.

This is all a mess lol. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From reading your message I understand you need the following catalog price rules:

1. A Product in the manufacturer "Ford" should apply a 25% discount
2. A Product in the manufacturer "Ford" and the category "Services" should apply a 45% discount

So without seeing all your catalog price rules and shopping cart rules I would do the following:

1. Check to see are there any other catalog price rules or shopping cart rules which are applying a discount. If there are then I would disable where you deem appropriate.
2. For the catalog price rule for 45% I would set the "priority" to "1" under "Rule Information" and then under "Actions" I would set "Stop Further Rules Processing" to "Yes".
3. For the catalog price rule for 25% would set the "priority" to "2" under "Rule Information" and then under "Actions" I would set "Stop Further Rules Processing" to "Yes".
4. Then back in "Catalog Price Rules" I would click "Apply Rules" (may take a while) and then clear the cache.

This will ensure that the 45% rule will be applied first and the 25% rule to be applied second. It will then stop any other "catalog price" rules been applied. However "Shopping Cart" rules may still apply as Magento system handles these separate to the "Catalog Price Rules".

Comment: Thanks for the reply Colin. I did try that, but then I get the issue of rounded up prices on random products of the 45% rule. 

Example: product price 9.5, discounted price gets 5.00, which is 47% reduction. 45% would be 5.23.

Comment: Hi John, Firstly if 45% of a reduction of 9.00"  is actually "4.95". Are there any other rules apart from the 2 rules you created. Can you also check Apply setting for both rules is "By Percentage of the Original Price". I have it working a vanilla install of RWD - http://postimg.org/image/8t0dw6amv/ and http://postimg.org/image/kiscumx0x/. Can you also see if a community or local module is changing the price? If you have a test version of the site, I would disable all extensions and reindex and clear the cache and then apply the rules again and see does that fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following solved my case:
[1.9.2 Catalogue Price Rules rounding (when more then one rule applied with 'Stop further rules..')](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108570/1-9-2-catalogue-price-rules-rounding-when-more-then-one-rule-applied-with-stop/110806#110806)

All I had to do then is to prioritize my rules as explained above. :)