# Catalog Price Rule - discount issue (possible rounding problem?)

Tags: magento-1.9, price, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

**SOLVED - see edit below**

I have a Product where the Price is £14.99. I have applied a Catalog Price Rule 50% off and the new price is showing as £7.00. I would expect it to be £7.49/£7.50.

If I knock the Price attr up to £15.00 and reapply the rule, the new special price is £7.50 as expected (so I don't think there is another rule conflicting). For other products where the Price starts at XX.00, these are being discounted as expected.

If I change the Price for this product to £13.99, then the special price is still £7.00. This is expected as 13.99 / 2 = 6.995.

Another product has a Price of £9.99 and is being discounted to £5.00 which is fine (due to rounding 4.995, I guess), but I don't understand why the £14.99 product is not behaving as expected, but the £9.99 is.

I have tried another product priced at £14.99 and this is also being discounted to £7.00.

Does anyone know why this would be happening? I'm confused. I've never noticed this before in Magento. It seems to be happening for every even number at .99:

15.00 -> 7.50 (correct)

14.99 -> 7.00 (wrong)

14.50 -> 7.00 (wrong)

13.99 -> 7.00 (correct)

13.00 -> 6.50 (correct)

12.99 -> 6.00 (wrong)

11.99 -> 6.00 (correct)

10.99 -> 5.00 (wrong)

9.99 -> 5.00 (correct)

Thanks

I am using Magento CE 1.9.2.4
We have Amasty Special Promotions module installed too, but I think this only affects Shopping Cart Rules?

**EDIT** See [1.9.2 Catalogue Price Rules rounding (when more then one rule applied with 'Stop further rules..')](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108570/1-9-2-catalogue-price-rules-rounding-when-more-then-one-rule-applied-with-stop) - this seems to be a bug with Magento 1.9.2.4, corrected in 1.9.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [1.9.2 Catalogue Price Rules rounding (when more then one rule applied with 'Stop further rules..')](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108570/1-9-2-catalogue-price-rules-rounding-when-more-then-one-rule-applied-with-stop) - this seems to be a bug with Magento 1.9.2.4, corrected in 1.9.3.1.

I applied the fix in that post and the issue is resolved.