# multiple catalog rules with same price, calculate wrong final price

Tags: catalog-price-rules, promotions, catalog-rules, magento1.9.3.1, magento-catalog

I have multiple catalog price rules on same product with same price but different priority, so i suppose that system will apply the lowest (0 is lowest) priority rule to calculate final price.

**Rule A:**

status: active, Priority:0,  action: to fixed amount, Discount: 223.200, Stop further rule: Yes

**Rule B:**

status: active, Priority:1, action: to fixed amount, Discount: 223.200, Stop further rule: yes

So I suppose final price has to be 223.200 by using Rule A. But Final price is coming 223.00.

I have no idea whats happening, can anyone has idea what possibly could be reason of this.

Comment: your magento version is 1.9.2.4 or lower ??

Comment: magento 1.9.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php`, in **method** `_calculatePrice()` around line 440:

```
$byFixed   => $this->_connection->getCheckSql(
                        new Zend_Db_Expr('0 > @price - cppt.action_amount'),
                        new Zend_Db_Expr('0'),
                        new Zend_Db_Expr('@price - cppt.action_amount')
                    ),
                )
            )
        ),
        '@price := @price' // <-- the culprit
    );
}
```

**replace with:**

```
     $byFixed   => $this->_connection->getCheckSql(
                        new Zend_Db_Expr('0 > @price - cppt.action_amount'),
                        new Zend_Db_Expr('0'),
                        new Zend_Db_Expr('@price - cppt.action_amount')
                    ),
                )
            )
        ),
        '@price' // remove ':= @price' to fix rounding bug
    );
}
```

[**Source**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/110806/45103)